# break statement remove only second loop

Tags: javascript, loops, break

i am using javascript nested loops and i need to break second loop on some condition but only second loop not the first one can anybody tell me how is it possible

**my code**

```
var myVar = "";
var i, j;

loopone:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
text += "<br>" + "i = " + i + ", j = ";

    looptwo:
    for (j = 10; j < 15; j++) {
        if (j === 12) {
            break;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += j + " ";
    }
}
```

not this break statement stop both loops but i want to stop only second loop.

Any help would be appriciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Mention the label of loop(`break [label];`)...`break looptwo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its so simple of you are using loops with label then you just have to mention the label(loop name) after break statement like this

```
var myVar = "";
var i, j;

loopone:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
text += "<br>" + "i = " + i + ", j = ";

    looptwo:
    for (j = 10; j < 15; j++) {
        if (j === 12) {
            break looptwo;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += j + " ";
    }
}
```

this will break only loop with name `looptwo`